# Add footer textbox shape to chart so it pastes with chart with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Some things are so hard in VBA. I wish I could use Python at work!

I want to add a textbox which works as a footer such that it stays with the chart when paste special as an image.

I can create the textbox on the right sheet with the right content.

**How do I get the textbox inside the chart like the title and legend?**

```
Sub AddChartFooter()

'Chart Names
    'WDLbyType
    'Top5byLDU
    'DurationbyLDU

Dim ws As Worksheet, s As Shape
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Charts")
    ' Create label (height/width will be set by AutoSize).
    Set s = ws.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 10, 10, 100, 100)
    s.TextFrame.Characters.Text = "Visualisations created by James Holiday-Scott"
    ' Resize text box to fit text.
    s.TextFrame.AutoSize = True
End Sub
```

Thanks!

Comment: Group the chart and Text box.  Something like `ws.Shapes.Range(Array(ws.ChartObjects(1).Name, s.Name)).Group`

Comment: Awesome - you should add that as an answer because it's a nifty solution. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Group the chart and Text box.

Something like

```vb
ws.Shapes.Range(Array(ws.ChartObjects(1).Name, s.Name)).Group
```

Answer (score 0):

A [Chart object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.chart(object)) has its own shapes collection. So you could add that text box there. Those shapes are contained in the chart then.

The main problem is the positioning. Following example adds text box to chart bottom left of chart area.

```
Sub AddChartFooter()

'Chart Names
    'WDLbyType
    'Top5byLDU
    'DurationbyLDU

Dim cht As Chart, chtShp As Shape, s As Shape
    ' Get a chart shape
    Set chtShp = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Charts").Shapes("WDLbyType")
    If chtShp.HasChart Then
        ' Get the chart
        Set cht = chtShp.Chart
        ' Create label (height/width will be set by AutoSize).
        Set s = cht.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 0, cht.ChartArea.Height, cht.ChartArea.Width, 0)
        s.TextFrame.Characters.Text = "Visualisations created by James Holiday-Scott"
        ' Resize text box to fit text.
        s.TextFrame.AutoSize = True
    End If
End Sub
```